# Convert table from article to beamer

Tags: beamer, color, tabu, html

I made the following table to be used in an article class document using \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} and \usepackage{tabu} and it works with no problems. However, now i need to use it in a beamer presentation and I am getting a lot of errors, what am I doing wrong?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\taburulecolor[HTML]{00CD5C}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
{\color[HTML]{00CD5C} \makecell{Nº Atos \\ Médicos \\ Anuais}} & {\color[HTML]{00CD5C} \makecell{Seguro \\ A}} & {\color[HTML]{00CD5C} \makecell{Seguro \\ B}} & {\color[HTML]{00CD5C} \makecell{Seguro \\ C}} \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 10}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 92}       & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 92}       & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 56}       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 20}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 92}       & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 124}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 108}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 30}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 110}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 188}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 160}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 40}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 146}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 252}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 212}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 50}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 182}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 316}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 264}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 60}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 218}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 380}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 316}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 70}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 254}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 444}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 368}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 80}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 290}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 508}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 420}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 90}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 326}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 572}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 472}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 100}                    & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 362}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 636}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 524}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 110}                    & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 398}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 700}     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 576}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 120}                    & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 434}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 764}     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 628}      \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\caption{Preço de atos médicos}
\label{Tab:Seg2}
\end{table}
```

Comment: If you want help with an error message it helps if you say what the error is (copied from the log file) and provide an example that produces the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `beamer` documentclass and reduce font size for text in table for a bit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{makecell, tabu}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table}
    \begin{table}
    \small
\taburulecolor[HTML]{00CD5C}
\begin{tabu}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
{\color[HTML]{00CD5C} \makecell{Nº Atos \\ Médicos \\ Anuais}} & {\color[HTML]{00CD5C} \makecell{Seguro \\ A}} & {\color[HTML]{00CD5C} \makecell{Seguro \\ B}} & {\color[HTML]{00CD5C} \makecell{Seguro \\ C}} \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 10}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 92}       & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 92}       & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 56}       \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 20}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 92}       & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 124}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 108}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 30}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 110}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 188}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 160}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 40}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 146}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 252}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 212}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 50}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 182}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 316}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 264}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 60}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 218}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 380}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 316}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 70}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 254}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 444}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 368}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 80}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 290}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 508}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 420}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 90}                     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 326}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 572}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 472}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 100}                    & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 362}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 636}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 524}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 110}                    & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 398}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 700}     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 576}      \\ \hline
{\color[HTML]{006CAD} 120}                    & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 434}      & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 764}     & {\color[HTML]{006CAD} 628}      \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
\caption{Preço de atos médicos}
\label{Tab:Seg2}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:** Use of `tabu` is not recommended. Package is not maintained. Instead it  simple `tabular` should be sufficient.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\newcommand\MC[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{} >{\color[HTML]{00CD5C}}c @{} } #1 \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Table}
    \begin{table}
    \small
    \arrayrulecolor[HTML]{00CD5C}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{>{\color[HTML]{006CAD}}c|} }
    \hline
\MC{Nº Atos \\ Médicos \\ Anuais}
    &   \MC{Seguro \\ A}
        &   \MC{Seguro \\ B}
            &   \MC{Seguro \\ C}    \\
    \hline
10  & 92  & 92  & 56  \\ \hline
20  & 92  & 124 & 108 \\ \hline
30  & 110 & 188 & 160 \\ \hline
40  & 146 & 252 & 212 \\ \hline
50  & 182 & 316 & 264 \\ \hline
60  & 218 & 380 & 316 \\ \hline
70  & 254 & 444 & 368 \\ \hline
80  & 290 & 508 & 420 \\ \hline
90  & 326 & 572 & 472 \\ \hline
100 & 362 & 636 & 524 \\ \hline
110 & 398 & 700 & 576 \\ \hline
120 & 434 & 764 & 628 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Preço de atos médicos}
\label{Tab:Seg2}
    \end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:**
Also in presentation `table` environments and `captions` are rarely used (see @Mico comment below). See if removing them is aceptable to you.

Comment: I wonder why you got downvoted?  I bumped you back to 0:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, apparently someone don't like me :-( Thank you very much

Comment: +1. Since the `table` environment doesn't float in a `beamer` document, I wouldn't use it. I'd simply replace `\frametitle{Table}` with `\frametitle{Preço de atos médicos}` and omit the`\caption` and `\label` directives.

Comment: @Mico, you are right. I was in doubt, do I use `table` or not. On the end I decide to use because OP use `caption` and then went even further and add beamer template for numbering caption. I will add to answer some comment about this.

Comment: @Zarko merci for your check :) I delete my comments above.